# How to detect handwriting from a picture. React Native

Tags: python, react-native, camera

I want to make a project, where user capture the visiting card, signboard, to-let etc by camera.

I want to avoid handwriting. If a user want to handwriting to a paper and take a picture. Then i want to detect it and remove it.

How can i do that?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I think you need some machine learning. You can use some NLP service to help you detect, or you can bundle some ML js lib into your app.